# Replication fails on user rights on SQL Server 2005 Reboot

Tags: sql-server

I had a replication job (transactional) on the same server between two databases set to use my domain account, which is admin on the box.

When I rebooted the box, the jobs failed, saying that my account wasn't an "owner."

I changed the owner and now the sub is requiring a re-initialize. What did I do wrong? Should I have made a SQL Server account to do the job? What rights should I have assigned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should never run SQL processes under your account.  Always run them under a dedicated domain account that is configured so that the password doesn't need to be reset.

How long has the replication been broken for?  After a certain point SQL will require that the subscriber be reinitialized.